# Jackson : field serialization format depending on other field value

Tags: java, json, jackson

I have the following Java class and I want to serialize it to JSON using Jackson:

```
public class Event
   boolean allDay;
   Date start;
   Date end;

   // get/set
}
```

But I want to format the Dates as "yyyy-MM-dd" when allDay is true and "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm" when allDay is false.  Is that possible?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's any built-in way to do that, which means you'll need to write some custom serialization code. [JsonDeserialize](http://jackson.codehaus.org/1.7.0/javadoc/org/codehaus/jackson/map/annotate/JsonDeserialize.html) is probably where you want to start.

You'll also have to make sure that the code which consumes the JSON knows how to deal with two alternate formats - and that's a whole separate mess. It might actually make more sense to just send the timestamps unformatted (I think the default is to write it as the number of milliseconds since the epoch) and ensure that the client code formats it appropriately before displaying to the user.

Comment: Thanks, Mike.  The format is imposed by a third party API so I have no control over it.  I've already written custom serializers for a single property (using JsonSerializer), but it does not allow me to add that rules (a field's format depends on other field's value).

Answer (score 1):

Mike's answer is correct, current serializer (and probably, deserializer) are obvious ways to go. I can't think of more specific support to handle co-constraints cases like this one.

For deserialization you could also consider using @JsonCreator for constructor (or static factory method): benefit is that you could define both boolean flag and String value to be passed, so it'd be bit simpler to have custom handling.